# sf guard does not display permission at sf_guard_user

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I'm working with Symfony for a few weeks now and I don't know well the sfPlugin and I'm working on a code that it doesn't written by me but I have to fix it anyway without reinstall itself.

**THE PROBLEM**:

I added a permission "perm_segreteria" to `sf_guard_permission`, but it isn't displayed in the form of `sf_guard_user`.

What I have to do/check to show in `sf_guard_user` form the new permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have only to add the permission widget in the generator of your module.

You can try to check inside 
*plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardUser/config/generator.yml*
if is set **sf_guard_user_permission_list** under *form - display*.

If this is your problem, you have to override the plugin module inside your symfony application 
(to be sure to not lose your changes when someonelse update the plugin);
basically add a structure of folders inside your app-folder named *sfGuardUser/config/generator.yml* 
then copy the content of the old *generator.yml* inside yours and make yours changes.